# Normalizing a truncated normal distribution

Tags: truncated-normal-distribution

If I have a normal distribution $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma)$, but I want to truncate it at 0, so that for all values below 0, the density is equal to 0 (like the blue density on the left plot below):
[image]

The density would be the truncated normal distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

I'm unsure how to calculate the pdf for the situation where $a=0$ and $b=\infty$.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be the PDF of the truncated normal distribution? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: If the underlying density is $f(x)$ and the underlying cumulative distribution function is $F(x)$ then the truncated density is $\dfrac{f(x)}{F(b)-F(a)}$ for $a < x < b$, and in this case $\dfrac{f(x)}{1-F(0)}$ for $0 < x$

Comment: Conventionally I would think (a) is right-skewed and (b) left-skewed

Comment: Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdf+trunc*+normal) for solutions.